# Stop the live updates while user is editing comment?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, state

I've a got a commenting system on my blog. Thing is the comments are updated live via WebSockets. While the comments are updated, of course the owner must be able to edit their comments. I want to enable in-place editing (which means that the comment will be replaced with a textbox and Save/Discard buttons). My React app subscribes to socket events and changes the `comments` array in the component state. This means that while the user is editing a comment, if something new comes in, the editing would be brutally stopped.

Having this said, I thought of two possible approaches:
 1. While the user is editing a comment, stop the live updates (i.e. temporarily ignore socket events)
 2. Keep updating the comments but keep scroll on the comment editor (which I don't know how to deal with)

I think it would be stupid to stop the live updates while the user is editing a comment, so I am asking you, how should go about keeping the editor there while updating comments?

**More about my application structure:**

I've got the component `<PostComments />` whose `state` contains the array `comments`. That array is being rendered then as a bunch of `<Comment />`:

```
renderComments = () => {
    const { comments } = this.state;

    return comments.map( comment => {
        return (
            <Comment key={comment['comment_id']} data={comment} />
        );
    } );
};
```

The `<Comment />` component gets static data to render (i.e. an object with a standard shape

```
export const commentDataType = React.PropTypes.shape( {
    comment_id: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    user_info: React.PropTypes.shape( {
        preferred_name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        profile_picture: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    } ).isRequired,
    post_timestamp: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    comment_text: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
} );
```

And this it kind of. Thank you!

Comment: Ideally you would keep live updating comments even while one is being edited, you just don't update that one.

Comment: So I should do something like `Array.filter` on `comments` and keep that one still?

Comment: Ideally create a copy of one that is being edited and edit the copy instead. That way you can discard changes just as easily and updates won't interfere with what the user is currently doing. It is just the one user who can update the one comment, right?

Comment: @ElodSzopos basically just one user, but what if the user is logged in on multiple terminals? (In this case, I intend to leave the terminals independent, I mean, I won't care if the user edits the comment from two terminals)

Comment: @Victor did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: @ElodSzopos I am sorry for not accepting your answer (I was so busy that I forgot). I solved the problem, your advice helped me a lot. I am accepting it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concluding from the brief conversation in the comments - by all means, I believe the best approach would be to save a copy of the comment separately somewhere in the state tree (possibly `currentlyEditing` or something similar) once the user opens it up for editing.

Then the user can edit the copy instead, and you can keep logic in the back intact as much as possible.

If the user commits, save the comment's changes for the comment with a specific `comment_id`.

Thinking forward, you could optionally introduce an `edited_timestamp` to make sure concurrent updates don't overwrite one-another and show a warning if the user doesn't have the latest changes and wants to save an edit.

This way you will keep the updates coming, the user flow and experience should not get disrupted and you will manage to re-use as much of your code as possible, while still getting the leniency and comfort of being able to discard edited changes at the click of a button, without worrying about side-effects.

You can often see similar behaviour and user-experience on forums and boards. Or blogs, very much similar to your use-case.